# Knockout validation for empty input

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I've got problem with getting knockout validation to work as I want to.
Let say we have ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.number = ko.observable("").extend({ pattern: new RegExp("^(\\d{10})$") });

    self.submitFunction = function () {
        if (self.number.isValid()) {
            //SUBMIT
        }
    };
}
```

In this situation when self.number is empty function return true. It's great when we are adding error messages( field is not red from the start). But when I'm submitting value it should be considered invalid and UI validation suppose to be updated.
What is good practice here?

Comment: Have you tried setting `required: true`?

Comment: Yes, but than validation is triggered on start and field is 'red' from the beginning. 
I have to apply error class not directly on input. It's done like that: data-bind="css: {error: !number.isValid()}

Comment: What's wrong with displaying the "this is required" hint right from the start? *(You can of course check `if (self.number.isValid() && self.number() != "")` but in a way that defies the purpose of the validation plugin.)*

Comment: Displaying all validation errors from the beginning( red fields etc.)
don't look 'nice'.
I didn't want to check for empty string there, but maybe I have to.

Comment: You could make it look 'nice' - showing people what's mandatory from the start is the right thing anyway. You could set a `self.attemptedSubmit = ko.observable(false);` and show more prominent warnings after the first attempt to submit the form was made.

Comment: This flag may by useful. I going to try this

Comment: Mariusz check the example fiddle from knockout validation github, it's not validated until user action, maybe you have a problem somewhere else? link: http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/2971/

Comment: This example is working fine. My problem is that I want to bind validation not to the input but to div above and data-bind="css: {error: !number.isValid()} will trigger validation right away or not at all.

Comment: @Wojciech-Czerniak Is there binding similar to validationMessage indicating that field is invalid and toggling class? 
Then maybe validation will be triggered as in fiddle example. 
<input type="text" data-bind="value: someValue"/>
<p data-bind="validationMessage: someValue"></p>